# Django money USD format is different

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using [django money](https://github.com/django-money/django-money) field in storing prices, and there's this little problem in displaying the values. The USD displayed format is different from the rest of the currency. See the displayed format below.

- USD: $1,000 *----> This should be 1,000 USD*
- SGD: 1,000 SGD
- CNY: 1,000 CNY

How come that USD is using currency sign ($) while the rest uses currency code? How do i set the USD to display currency code? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make the _FORMATTER work by setting `USE_L10N = False`

In their documentation it says:

> The formatting is turned on if you have set USE_L10N = True in the
>   your settings file. If formatting is disabled in the configuration,
>   then in the templates will be used default formatting. In the
>   templates you can use a special tag to format the money.

Answer (score 1):

In settings.py:

```
from moneyed.localization import _FORMATTER
_FORMATTER.add_sign_definition('default', moneyed.USD, suffix =' USD')
```

If there is `prefix` inside `add_sign_definition()`, remove it.

Comment: I've already added this in my settings but still displaying the wrong format. Now i realized that my settings are not taking effect. :( 

`import moneyed
from moneyed.localization import _FORMATTER

CURRENCIES = ('USD', 'AUD', 'SGD', 'EUR', 'CNY', 'BRL', 'CAD')
CURRENCY_DECIMAL_PLACES = 0

_FORMATTER.add_sign_definition(
    'default',
    moneyed.USD,
    prefix='',
    suffix=' USD'
)

_FORMATTER.add_sign_definition(
    'default',
    moneyed.AUD,
    prefix='AUD '
)

_FORMATTER.add_sign_definition(
    'default',
    moneyed.SGD,
    prefix='SGD '
)`

Comment: @bwaaaaaa Does it work not? If everything else fails, do USD amounts manually by using {{value.amount}} USD

Comment: No it didn't work. Also i've set the prefix but it seems that the currency code is appended as suffix. I have no idea what's happening on this. I wish i can do your suggestion, too bad that the currency is dynamic. :(

Comment: @bwaaaaaa Try {{value.amount}} {{value.currency}}

Comment: thanks for your response. Finally, I was able to make it work.